# Why does the Oracle Java compiler prefer the no-args StringBuilder constructor?

Tags: java, javac, bytecode, compiler-optimization

Purely out of interest I've been looking at how the Oracle Java compiler handles `String` concatenation and I'm seeing something I didn't expect.

Given the following code:

```java
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s = "Test" + getSpace() + "String.";
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }

    // Stops the compiler optimising the concatenations down to a
    // single string literal.
    static String getSpace() {
        return " ";
    }
}
```

I expected that the compiler would optimise it to the equivalent of:

```java
String s = new StringBuilder("Test").append(getSpace())
                   .append("String.").toString();
```

But it actually compiles down to the equivalent of:

```java
String s = new StringBuilder().append("Test").append(getSpace())
                   .append("String.").toString();
```

I'm compiling this using the 32-bit jdk1.7.0_55 release. This is the output of `javap -v -l`:

```
public class StringTest
  SourceFile: "StringTest.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #14.#25        //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #26            //  java/lang/StringBuilder
   #3 = Methodref          #2.#25         //  java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   #4 = String             #27            //  Test
   #5 = Methodref          #2.#28         //  java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   #6 = Methodref          #13.#29        //  StringTest.getSpace:()Ljava/lang/String;
   #7 = String             #30            //  String.
   #8 = Methodref          #2.#31         //  java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   #9 = Fieldref           #32.#33        //  java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #10 = Methodref          #34.#31        //  java/lang/String.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  #11 = Methodref          #35.#36        //  java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #12 = String             #37            //
  #13 = Class              #38            //  StringTest
  #14 = Class              #39            //  java/lang/Object
  #15 = Utf8               <init>
  #16 = Utf8               ()V
  #17 = Utf8               Code
  #18 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #19 = Utf8               main
  #20 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #21 = Utf8               getSpace
  #22 = Utf8               ()Ljava/lang/String;
  #23 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #24 = Utf8               StringTest.java
  #25 = NameAndType        #15:#16        //  "<init>":()V
  #26 = Utf8               java/lang/StringBuilder
  #27 = Utf8               Test
  #28 = NameAndType        #40:#41        //  append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  #29 = NameAndType        #21:#22        //  getSpace:()Ljava/lang/String;
  #30 = Utf8               String.
  #31 = NameAndType        #42:#22        //  toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  #32 = Class              #43            //  java/lang/System
  #33 = NameAndType        #44:#45        //  out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #34 = Class              #46            //  java/lang/String
  #35 = Class              #47            //  java/io/PrintStream
  #36 = NameAndType        #48:#49        //  println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #37 = Utf8
  #38 = Utf8               StringTest
  #39 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #40 = Utf8               append
  #41 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  #42 = Utf8               toString
  #43 = Utf8               java/lang/System
  #44 = Utf8               out
  #45 = Utf8               Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #46 = Utf8               java/lang/String
  #47 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
  #48 = Utf8               println
  #49 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
{
  public StringTest();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    LineNumberTable:
      line 2: 0
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 2: 0

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_VARARGS
    LineNumberTable:
      line 4: 0
      line 5: 27
      line 6: 37
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
         7: ldc           #4                  // String Test
         9: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        12: invokestatic  #6                  // Method getSpace:()Ljava/lang/String;
        15: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        18: ldc           #7                  // String String.
        20: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        23: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        26: astore_1
        27: getstatic     #9                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        30: aload_1
        31: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/String.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        34: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        37: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
        line 5: 27
        line 6: 37

  static java.lang.String getSpace();
    flags: ACC_STATIC
    LineNumberTable:
      line 10: 0
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: ldc           #12                 // String
         2: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
}
```

Anecdotally, I've read [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/java-stringbuilder-myth-debunked.html) that the ECJ compiler **does** actually compile down to the argumented constructor (although I haven't verified it for myself), so my question is *why doesn't Oracle's compiler make that same optimisation*?

---

Based on the comments I ran another test using a longer `String` so as to immediately exceed the default length of the `StringBuilder`'s backing `char[]`:

```java
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s = "Testing a much, much longer " + getSpace() + "String.";
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }

    // Stops the compiler optimising the concatenations down to a single string literal
    static String getSpace() {
        return " ";
    }
}
```

With the exception of the contents of the literals being slightly different, the generated bytecode is exactly the same, still using the no-args constructor to instantiate the `StringBuilder` before appending to it. In this situation the argumented constructor version of the code *should* out-perform the no-args one as far as I can tell. This is due to the need to re-size the backing `char[]` at the first call to `append()`, and then *potentially* needing to do it again on the next `append()` if the appended `String` was particularly large.

---

On AnubianNoob's suggestion I did a quick performance test of `System.arraycopy(...)` to see if it was indeed optimised for empty arrays. This is the code used:

```java
public class ArrayCopyTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {

        char[] array = new char[16];
        final long test1Start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, array, 0, array.length);
        }

        final long test1End = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Elapsed Time (empty array copies)");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println((test1End - test1Start) + "ns");

        char[] array2 = new char[] {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
             '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

        final long test2Start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array2, 0, array2.length);
        }

        final long test2End = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Elapsed Time (non-empty array copies)");
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println((test2End - test2Start) + "ns");
    }
}
```

Running this on a Windows 7.1 32-bit machine with an i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40 GHz 3.39 GHz and 3.24 GB of usable RAM produced:

```
Elapsed Time (empty array copies)
=================================
26660199ns
Elapsed Time (non-empty array copies)
=====================================
19431962ns
```

<strike>I ran this about five times just to be sure. It actually appears that it performs better over a million iterations when the array *isn't* empty.</strike> As Mike Strobel correctly pointed out, the above isn't a meaningful benchmark.

Comment: Why do you believe that to be an optimisation? The only difference between the two is the capacity, which is larger when using the string-based constructor.

Comment: @Duncan I'm not suggesting that one version is necessarily better than the other (I haven't delved deep enough to form an informed opinion on that), I'm just interested to know why Oracle prefers the no-args constructor when ECJ prefers the argumented one. If I were to write the code manually I would have used the argumented constructor, so I (perhaps naively) assumed that that's what the compiler would do as well.

Comment: @Duncan Having looked a little more closely, if the initial `String` that gets appended to the `StringBuilder` is longer than 16 characters then the backing `char[]` will be expanded immediately to a length of *at least* 34, with some spare capacity if the `String` is shorter than 34 characters. If it's longer than 34 characters then the new array will be exactly long enough to fit the new contents, meaning that the next call to `append()` will again cause the array to be resized. Given that, I'd argue that the parameterised constructor would be a better option for the compiler to pick...

Comment: ...because it ensures that it's large enough to hold the initial `String` to begin with and has 16 characters of spare capacity left over at the end.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a meaningful benchmark.  Benchmarking with Java is tricky business, and you have to account for things like delayed JIT.  If the first test case consistently runs slower, I'd bet you lunch that the results would change if you swapped the order of the tests :).

Comment: @MikeStrobel I'm relatively inexperienced with benchmarking so it wouldn't surprise me if that does turn out to be the case. I'll give it a test now that I'm home.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Well I've rerun it about a dozen times using the existing setup and with the tests reversed, and I'm seeing huge variations on my home computer, whereas my work computer was at least consistent. Sometimes the empty array is faster, sometimes the full one is. I figure that probably renders the benchmark meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is just laziness. Why? Since if you pick the arg-constructor, you need further checks. You have to check whether the first expression to be concatenated is a string, if so, you can use the arg constructor, otherwise, you have to fall back to the no-arg constructor. This is just a lot more logic than simply always taking the no-arg constructor.

If I was that compiler developer, I would have chosen the easy way, too, since implicit string concatenation is surely not the bottleneck in many applications and the difference is so small that it is just not worth the hassle.

Most people think of compilers as magic programs designed by super humans that always do the best things. But this is not true, compilers are also written by usual programmers which do not always think hours about what is *the* best way to compile any specific thing. They have tight schedules and need features to get done, so the easiest solution is often the one of choice.

Comment: This is probably the reason.  Perhaps not incidentally, if you always use the same pattern, optimizing the operation at runtime becomes easier too.

Comment: I do find myself curious why there are no `String` constructors that accept either multiple arguments or a `String[]`.  Given a `String` constructor with a `String[]` argument, constructing and populating a `String[]` and passing it to that constructor would probably be faster than using `StringBuilder` every scenario (it would only require constructing a total of one temporary object).

Answer (score 4):

Probably because the `String` constructor calls `append()` anyways:

```
public StringBuilder(String str) {
    super(str.length() + 16);
    append(str);
}
```

Comment: So, you are saying that there is no difference and Oracle just picks a random solution. Right?

Comment: @Val Possibly? There could be some reasoning as to letting the capacity expand "naturally" instead of setting it directly, or some way the JIT compiler is written, but a more specific reason I'm not aware of.

Comment: If you do not know then how do you answer? The question asks for what you do not know.

Comment: Because I can provide a reasonable guess, I suppose? Only someone who actually wrote the compiler code dealing with this can give an authoritative answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because JVM optimizes String concatination and it is probably better for it to recognize String concatination pattern in bytecode the way it is implemented now.

Comment: Do you mean that it might be easier to spot an empty `StringBuilder` constructor call?

Comment: It's probably not so much that it's easier to spot an empty constructor call, but it simplifies the pattern recognition if you only have one pattern to look for.  The compiler couldn't use the parameterized constructor in *all* cases (e.g., for `1 + "one"`), but it *can* use the empty constructor in all cases.

Comment: @MikeStrobel That does make a lot of sense, I hadn't thought about it that way. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

As another person has mentioned, the `StringBuilder` class calls `append()` in its constructor, and it's a lot more readable and consistent to have an append yourself.

Consider:

```
new StringBuilder("Hello").append("World");
new StringBuilder().append("Hello").append("World");
```

This might not be the best example, but two appends is a lot simpler to see than passing it into the constructor. And the speed is the same.

Comment: I agree that the speed would be the same in this specific example (and in my own example as well), but if your initial `String` was longer than 16 characters it would cause the `AbstractStringBuilder` to reallocate its `char[]` to hold the `String`, which wouldn't be required if using the parameterised constructor.

Comment: @JonK Actually what happens if you do it with a String longer than 16 characters?

Comment: `append()` calls out to `AbstractStringBuilder#ensureCapacity(int)` first using the input `String`'s length as an argument. The no-args constructor sets the initial capacity to 16, so if the `String` is longer than that then it will call `expandCapacity(int)` and increase the array's capacity to 34 or the `String`'s length, whichever is the greater. Or did you mean in terms of the generated bytecode?

Comment: I just did a quick test with a longer `String` and the generated bytecode was the same (with the obvious exception that the `String`'s contents were different) - it still uses the no-args constructor. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: @JonK That's interesting... Would `arrayCopy` be optimized for empty arrays? This is probably worth profiling...

Comment: From the tests I just ran (I've added the code and output to the question) it actually appears that `System.arraycopy` performs a bit better on a non-empty array. However it was hardly an exhaustive test, so perhaps needs to be expanded upon...

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there are related issues in JDK issue tracker: [JDK-4059189](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4059189) and related. The initial proposal is dated 1997! And there are not much discussion there. This means that this issue is either considered unimportant or this case is optimized by JIT.